# Why this AWK command deletes a character when the console width is filled?

Tags: bash, awk

The command is

```
 tail -f log | stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 $AWK '{print $0,"\n"; fflush();}'
```

[image]

You can see that we miss the "o" in "option". This character deletion happens every in every line.

Comment: With those colors I can't see anything but if it is in the beginning of a line I'd guess that the file has `\r\n` line endings and that causes it.

Answer (score 0):

I've replaced the command with

```
stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0 sed --unbuffered '0~1 a\\'
```